# Minimize array and output the remainder with respect to 1 second time limit

Tags: python, python-2.x, time-limit-exceeded

This is my code:

```
n = int(raw_input())
seq = raw_input().split()
def minimize_list(lst):
    new_lst = []
    k = len(lst)
    for i in range(k-1):
        new_lst.append(lst[i+1]-lst[i])
    return new_lst
for i in range(len(seq)):
    seq[i] = int(seq[i])
final_list = []
for num in seq:
    final_list.append(num)
while len(final_list) != 1:
    final_list = minimize_list(final_list)
print (final_list[0])%(1000000000+7)
```

It takes a number and a sequence of numbers. (The first number is the number of numbers in the sequence). It then calculates a shorter sequence with the difference of adjacent numbers until there is just 1 number. Unfortunately, The time complexity is not good enough. I have to make it better to meet the time limit which is 1 second.

Any idea?

Note: I cannot see the input. I can just pass my code to a server which has 10 examples and runs my code on them. The server then tells me that this code has exceeded the time limit for some examples.

Update: I want to print (final_list[0])%(1000000000+7)

Comment: Do you have any example input and output? This usually makes these problems way easier to understand.

Comment: @Graipher I do not know anything about the input.

Comment: Do you at least have a link to the problem statement?

Comment: @Graipher I do! But it's in Persian (not English)

Answer (score 2):

One easy way is to use [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), which is implemented in C (if it is available on the machine your online judge is running on). It provides fast ways to do numerical calculations. In this case, you can use [`numpy.diff`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html), which calculates the difference between elements. It even has a `n` argument, so it applies it `n` times. We also know how often we need to apply it to get only a single element, `len(seq) - 1` times:

```
import numpy as np

n = int(raw_input())
seq = map(int, raw_input().split())
print np.diff(seq, len(seq) -1)[0]
```

---

If you need to stick to built-in methods, you could at least make the `minimize_list` method a bit shorter using a [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python) (and maybe rename it to `diff`):

```
def diff(x):
    return [b - a for a, b in zip(x, x[1:])]

def reduce_diff(seq):
    while len(seq) > 1:
        seq = diff(seq)
    return seq[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(raw_input())
    seq = map(int, raw_input().split())
    print reduce_diff(seq)
```

I also removed the redundant copying from `seq` to `final_list` and instead of the `for` loop to convert all values to integers I used `map`.

Be aware that if you want to use this with Python 3 (as you should, since [Python 2 will be obsolete soon](https://pythonclock.org/)), you need to surround that `map` call with a call to `list` and replace `raw_input` with `input`.

In addition I added a [`if __name__ == "__main__":` guard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) to allow importing from this script from another script.

---

And finally, one can notice that this approach is \$\mathcal{O}(n^2)\$. When looking at a simple example of successive application of `diff`, a pattern becomes obvious:

\$
a, b, c, d, e\\
b-a, c-b, d-c, e-d\\
c-2b+a,d-2c+b, e-2d+c\\
d-3c+3b-a, e-3d+3c-b\\
e-4d+6c-4b+a
\$

The coefficients are the ones from [Pascals triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle), together with an alternating sign:

\$
\begin{pmatrix}
 & & & & 1 & & & &\\
 & & & 1 & & 1 & & & \\
 & & 1 & & 2 & & 1 & & \\
 & 1 & & 3 & & 3 & & 1 & \\
1 & & 4 & & 6 & & 4 & & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\$

So, if you find a [fast way to calculate the n-th row of Pascal's triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40067792/4042267), you can solve this problem in \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$, by adding the terms with a plus, modulo p and the ones with a minus, modulo p and then subtract them:

```
from itertools import cycle

def pascal_line(n):
    line = [1]
    mid, even = divmod(n, 2)
    line_append = line.append
    for k in xrange(1, mid + 1):
        num = line[k-1]*(n + 1 - k)//(k)
        line_append(num)
    reverse_it = reversed(line)
    if not even:
        next(reverse_it)
    line.extend(reverse_it)
    return line

def reduce_pascal(seq):
    return sum(sign * c * x
               for sign, c, x in zip(cycle([1, -1]),
                                     pascal_line(len(seq)-1),
                                     reversed(seq)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = int(raw_input())
    seq = map(int, raw_input().split())
    p = 1000000000+7
    print reduce_pascal(seq) % p
```

One could make this also modular `p` at each step by doing the `sum` manually and enforcing the mod `p`.

Beware: This seems to break down for large sequences (since the terms in the triangle get big).

Comment: Isn't there any built-in module instead of numpy? The server does not support it.

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh Added some built-in code.

Comment: Actually, I want to print (seq[0])%(1000000000+7) . Is there a fast way to calculate that value with built-in functions? (I know i didn't mention that in my question. But just in case you know...)

Comment: I uploaded the code to the server and it's still not good enough.

Comment: It seems that i cannot import anything (including that cycle you wrote). Any other way ?

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh: Wow, not being able to import even `itertools`, which is in the standard library, is mean.

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh: You can always add your own definition of `cycle` (see updated answer).

Comment: Excuse me for my wrong information. That was not the problem. This time i exceeded the memory limit which is 256 MB. The server says that there are 10 examples and 7 of them is fine. 2 has exceeded memory limit and 1 has exceeded time limit.

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh: In that case I'm out of ideas for now...

Comment: It may help that you can calculate the binomial coefficients modulo a prime number p with [Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem), that will limit the size of intermediate results. For the special case p=3 that was done [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/197642/35991).